# Editor with caching like Notepad++ in windows

Tags: text-editor, editor, notepadqq

Is there an editor for linux which can cache files in it? Every time I started the Notepad++ on windows, it brought all files which I've left open (even unsaved files).

Unfortunately the Notepadqq doesn't brings up this function. Does anybody have a recommendation?

Comment: Don't know about a native application but Notepadd++ works pretty decent with PlayOnLinux. **//EDIT:** SublimeText can do this but it's not free, though you can use the trial version for as long as you want.

Comment: Gedit has also a plugin to save the session. See this thread [http://askubuntu.com/questions/51944/remember-what-files-are-opened-in-a-session-of-gedit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51944/remember-what-files-are-opened-in-a-session-of-gedit)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu have plenty of editor. Here are two options:

- You can use [Gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) with plugin ([gedit-restore-tabs](https://github.com/raelgc/gedit-restore-tabs)).
- [Atom](https://atom.io/) is a very powerful editor with a tons of plugins, [save-session](https://atom.io/packages/save-session) or [remember-session](https://atom.io/packages/remember-session) will does the trick.

Comment: Sublime Text also does this by default.

Answer (score 1):

[Notapadqq](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/s/) has caching as default. Is a pretty good alternative that does most of the things that Notepad++ does. Here is a the [github repo](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Atom Editor

https://atom.io/

if anything is missing, most likely you can find additional packages that will do what you want!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but Geany (`sudo apt-get install geany`) restores previous files and tabs from last session.

Also you can install Notepad++ on wine if you like it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) for Linux. It has auto completition, words highlighting and themes, plugins, extensions...